# Recursion with trigonometric functions

Tags: trigonometry, recurrence-relations, recursion

I have to solve a very strange recurrence relation. 
Has anyone an idea how to derive a closed formula for $r_i$?
At least a 'good' upper bound would be nice.
Currently I have no idea how to solve this...

Thanks for your help.

For the recurrence, $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

\begin{align*}
r_0 &= \frac{n}{2\pi} \\
r_i &= r_{i-1} - \frac{\sin \left(\frac{\pi\cdot(n-2)}{2n} + \arcsin \left (\frac{2\pi\cdot r_{i-1}}{n} \cdot \sin \left( \frac{\pi\cdot(n-2)}{2n}\right) \right) \right)}{2 \cdot \sin\left( \frac{\pi\cdot(n-2)}{2n}\right)}
\end{align*}

Comment: Is $m$ a typo for $n?$

Comment: Yes, sorry for that

Comment: When $n=2$ the denominator is $0$.  You can simplify this expression.  $$\sin\left(\pi(n-2)\over2n\right)=\cos{\pi\over n}$$

Comment: You can simplify a bit. Writing $t := \pi(n-2)/(2n)$ and $s := 2\pi r_{i-1}/n$, the numerator of the fraction becomes 
$$
\begin{align}\sin\left(\; t + \arcsin( s \sin t)\;\right) &= \sin t \cos\arcsin( s \sin t ) + \cos t \sin\arcsin( s\sin t) \\
&= \sin t \left( \sqrt{1-s^2 \sin^2 t} + s \cos t \right)
\end{align}$$
whereupon the $\sin t$ in the denominator cancels. And, as @saulspatz notes, you can write $\sin t = \cos(\pi/n)$ and $\cos t = \sin(\pi/n)$.

Comment: Perhaps this is a "bad" upper bound, but it's a start:. *Assuming* the recurrence is valid for all $i$, in order for the $\arcsin$ to always be defined, we must have $$\left|\frac{2\pi r_{i}}{n}\;\sin\frac{\pi(n-2)}{n}\right| \leq 1 \quad\to\quad \left|r_i\right| \leq r_0\,\sec\frac{\pi}{n} $$